# Mocking imported class instances in Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am importing a class instance from an external library and using directly in a class member like so:

```
import { MyClient } from '@foo/bar';

export class DoStuff {

    public getStuff = () => {
        return MyClient.fetchThings();
    }
}
```

The library from which I am importing this class, exports the class like so:

```
// my-client.ts

class MyClient {
  //stuff
  async fetchThings() {
  }
}

export const myClient =  new MyClient();

-----

// index.ts

export {
  myClient as MyClient,
} from './my-client';
```

I want to be able to stub out the imported `MyClient` class instance in my DoStuff class of the consuming application, but I am unsure how to do so.

I was considering using [ts-mock-imports](https://github.com/EmandM/ts-mock-imports) but their examples seem to cover cases where you want to new up an imported class in the class you are testing against.

In my case, the imported class is already an instance.

Whats the right approach here?

Comment: Use services. https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Comment: There is several approaches, the simplest would just remove the import and just create the class `class MyClient` in your .spec.ts file

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question since this is making use of a class imported from outside of Angular, so I think my use case is somewhat different

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to use [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services). Never directly import the instance, but let Angular inject the instance. That way, services easily can be [mocked by injecting the mocked service](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#testing-components-with-dependencies).

You can create a wrapper over `MyClient` as an injectable service and let Angular inject it into `DoStuff`. Then, in the tests you can pass a [mocked](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#testing-components-with-dependencies) `MyClientService`.

```
import { MyClientService } from './my-client-service';

export class DoStuff {
    myClientService: MyClientService;

    constructor(myClientService) {
        this.myClientService = myClientService;
    }

    public getStuff = () => {
        return this.myClientService.fetchThings();
    }
}
```

my-client-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyClient } from '@foo/bar';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyClientService {
     myClient: MyClient;

    constructor() {
        this.myClient = MyClient;
    }

    fetchThings() {
        return this.myClient.fetchThings();
    }
}
```

See also the example in the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question since this is making use of a class imported from outside of Angular

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can write a wrapper over `MyClient ` which then can be used as injectable service.